# Is there a way to implement an abortController in aws' auth.signIn method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

The requirement was to check an already signed in user, if they entered the correct password for a change password feature:

```js
  const handleConfirmPassword = async (pw: string) => {
    if (pw.length < 8) {
      return;
    }
    
    if (controllerRef.current) {
      controllerRef.current.abort();
    }

    controllerRef.current = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controllerRef.current;

    await Auth.signIn(user.id, pw, { abortSignal: signal });
  }
```

I wanted to validate the password on user input or just cancel the previous request if the user changes the input. Is there an alternative way to do this?